# amazon-linux-extras enable vs install

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-linux-extras

What is the difference between `amazon-linux-extras enable` and `amazon-linux-extras install`? I am asking because a recent change in our `build.sh` broke our AWS build - `amazon-linux-extras enable ansible2` became `amazon-linux-extras install ansible2`.

After that the build started failing with:

```
Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install.
```

I added a version check - `ansible --version || exit 1` and it passes for `amazon-linux-extras enable ansible2` which means that it too installs it (but somehow manages not to fail).

So what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

`amazon-linux-extras enable ansible2` only enables the ansible yum repositories.

`amazon-linux-extras install ansible2` enables the yum repositories and installs the latest version of ansible 2.